# what is the right way of loading javascript module in the xbl/ xul file?

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, firefox-addon, xul

I am developing an extension in Firefox. I want to load a simple javascript module to my xbl file. I have followed the instructions in [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_JavaScript_code_modules#resource-urls) but I don't get any results. In fact when I call the method inside the handler it doesn't execute.

This is my file structure for extensions

-Magic/chrome/urltooltip/content/(browse.xbl, options.xul, browser.css)

-Magic/modules/(test.js)

I have registered resource in chrome manifest: resource app chrome://modules/test.js or resource gre chrome://modules/test.js it doesn't work.

in the xbl file I imported the file like this:

Components.utils.import(resource://app|gre/modules/test.js)

I don't know what else to do.

Comment: This question was answered in the mozilla.dev.extensions newsgroup.

Comment: I didn't get any response from here so I added this questions over there and got the answer. thanks

Comment: You should post the answer you received here and accept it

Comment: Can you please share the answer from mozilla.dev.extensions newsgroup I'm interested in this

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<window xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

  <script src="foo.js"></script>

  <script>
    <[CDATA[
      function bar() {}
    ]]>
  </script>

  <caption label="Hello World"/>

</window>
```